# Change background of shape functioning as view's background

Tags: android, button, background

I am using a shape in order to make my button look round and have a background (from the layouts folder):

main layout:

```
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/registerButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@layout/circle_button"/>
```

circle_button.xml:

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
android:id = "@+id/circle_background">
<solid android:background = "@drawable/start_record_icon"></solid>
</shape>
```

problem is, I want to change the background of the shape to a given icon (also a drawable) according to some variables in the activity. If I define a background in the XML, how can I change it dynamically? (I could create 3 different layouts of shapes with different backgrounds but that seems stupid)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: So what I'm getting now is something like this (if I change the color of the solid in the shape to white, because otherwise the icon doesn't show at all and I see nothing. Buttons in the right bottom corner):

[image]

So I have a few problems, actually: one is that I cannot set the size of the buttons (if I try to set in the `<Button>`, it becomes square; if I try in the shape or in the solid it does nothing), second is that I cannot apply the icons or change them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an ImageView, by calling [setBackgroundResource(int resource)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)) with your business logic.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

if (isCircle()) {
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_button);
}
else {
    // TODO use different XML drawable
}
```

Within your layout XML, you should then specify equal width and height, and use the [src attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:src) to set your icon.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:src="@drawable/my_icon" />
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that method but it doesn't allow me to change the drawable that I want to use - suppose I want to go from one icon to another, not just change colors...

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what you mean by icon?

Comment: added, thanks for the help. What I'm trying to add is icon - like the ic_launcher, which will act as the background of the circle_button's background and then the circle_button will act as the button's background. I've also managed to get the button circle by creating the image asset as a circle (instead of None or Square)

Comment: If you are not setting text on the button, it might make more sense to use an ImageView. The background can then be set to your XML layout, and the icon can be set using the src attribute (or dynamically, using setImageDrawable()).

Comment: So in order to make the imageView oval, I could use the android:shape tag or...?

Comment: Just set the layout_width and layout_height to be equal e.g. 72dp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98743/discussion-between-fitzchivalry-and-fractalwrench).